# Detecting Slow Network on Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

My App is built on Ionic V1, I have added Network info plugin for detecting an Internet connection. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

But the problem is it doesn't address the case of slow networks. Is there a way to detect that.

BTW I'm using angular-fire which in turn uses WebSocket (I guess) so timeouts with $http cannot be feasible in this case (Even though I perform some $http calls).

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following [Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/) you can measure the type of connections your device is making use and based upon that you could do actions.

```
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
```

If for example you pick `CELL_2G` it will represent the following speed

> 2G Data Transmission Capacity: With General Packet Radio Service
>   (GPRS), there is a theoretical maximum transfer speed of 50 kbit/s (40
>   kbit/s in practice). With EDGE (Enhanced Data Rates for GSM
>   Evolution), there is a theoretical maximum transfer speed of 1 Mbit/s
>   (500 kbit/s in practice).

Comment: But what if he is connected to Wifi but has poor speed?

Comment: Any other solution for slow wifi? Web service response is very slow due to slow internet connection so data is not loading properly.

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix what's the response rate of the server, try to optimize this after that look into service workers https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers at least if it's an PWA